# Installing Extensions from the store via the windows registry

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I want to add some keys into the windows registry and let firefox to install my extension from the store. Is it possible?
After reading [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry) I can create my extension key here: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions in the following format:
MyExtensionId = LocalPath. It works pretty well, Firefox installs my extension during the next launch.

However, now I am interested how to install an extension the same way but from the store (https://addons.mozilla.org/).
If I just write URL to the registry instead LocalPath, it doesn't work.

What is the exact format of registry keys which I have to write to achieve my goal?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? Self-answer if you did, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I learned this question it's impossible to install an extension from the store using the windows registry. Fortunately, it's possible to sign your extension in the mozzila store, download the signed extension, include it to your installer, then distribute this signed extension with your installer and then install your extension as usually through the registry.

Answer (score 0):

I know that now it is impossible. I tried to solve this problem. For example, installing an extension "uBlock Origin" via CMD script. It works:

reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions /v uBlock0@raymondhill.net /d D:\Download\ublock_origin-1.18.6-an+fx.xpi

But, it isn't:

reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions /v uBlock0@raymondhill.net /d https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/1709472/ublock_origin-1.18.6-an+fx.xpi /f

In Chrome browser, the installation from the URL works! We'll wait until Firefox browser developers come to this too.